# how to stop picture moving whie scrolling, css background-position: fixed;

Tags: html, css

I made the "glass" (blur) effect on a div with `background-img`, but I don't want the background to move when scrolling.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/metsuge/pen/gOaZzzM

Any ideas?

HTML

```
<div class="each-img">
  <div class="text-container-glass"></div>
</div>
<div class="each-img">
  <div class="text-container-glass"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.each-img {  
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 600px;
  height:400px;
  background-image: url("https://images2.minutemediacdn.com/image/upload/c_crop,h_1414,w_2101,x_10,y_0/v1554702738/shape/mentalfloss/49786-istock_0.jpg?itok=C4VA9VSs");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.text-container-glass{
  background: inherit;
  width: 50%;
  height: 120px; 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.text-container-glass{
  background: inherit;
  width: 50%;
  height: 120px; 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.text-container-glass:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  filter: blur(12px);
}
```

It seems that the `background-image` is fixed to the screen itself, not the div `each-img`

Comment: Are you attempting to achieve the parallax effect?

Comment: As I understand, parallax is when you scroll and all the elements are moving (like text), but the background image is not. I need the opposite, where the background image is moving like a normal element.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Try remove this line `background-attachment: fixed;` in your `.each-img {  }` CSS. This will make the image be fixed relative to the screen inside the div element. Maybe that was what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

set `background-attachment: scroll;` on `.each-img`

Comment: This does fix the scrolling thing, but the blurred div now is like the same picture as the background, and not 'transparent'

Comment: Is this another issue? The blurred div is different because of the change of scrolling thing? Or it is the same for both fixed and scroll background-attachment?

Comment: You may use `opacity` property to control the transparency of the div

Comment: the blurr effect is ok, but now it looks as two pictures, one on top on another. I want it to be that the div has the same background part, relative to the parent div background. The goal is that only the div part of the background is blurred.

Comment: sorry, I don't think I can do that.